# How to connect to mail server in C

Tags: linux, smtp, mail-server, unix, sendmail

I tried to make a connection to my mail server which is in local area network. The ip of mail server is 192.168.1.1. So, I tried the
following program to test that.

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    struct in_addr ip;

    int fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.1.1",&ip)==-1){
        printf("Unable to convert ip to binary\n");
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port=25;
    sa.sin_addr=ip;

    if(connect(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&sa,sizeof(sa))==-1){
        printf("Unable to connect to server\n");
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("Successfully connected to server...\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Unable to connect to server
Connection refused
$
```

But via telnet, it is successfully connected as shown below.

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.1 25
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.msys.co.in ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
$
```

So, what is the mistake I done here. Is there anything wrong in my program. I request you to help me solve this problem and why it occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to mail server in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239576/how-to-connect-to-mail-server-in-c)

Comment: Please don't cross-post again, to off-topic sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disregarding any other problems, what causes the direct breakage in the question is (almost certainly, barring "unexpected" host architecture):

```
sa.sin_port=25;
```

What you need is something like this:

```
sa.sin_port = htons(25);
```

Ie, you have the wrong byte order for the port number, meaning it will be interpreted as some other number entirely.

From htons(3):

> The htons() function converts the unsigned short integer hostshort from
>     host byte order to network byte order.
>
> [snip]
>
> On the i386 the host  byte  order  is  Least  Significant  Byte  first,
>      whereas  the  network byte order, as used on the Internet, is Most Sig‐
>      nificant Byte first.

Even if you were developing on an architecture where the host byte order matched the network byte order (ie, both MSB), you'd want to do the conversion to allow for portability.